# Changing Arrays In ngFor (Angular2)

Tags: angular

I got a service which returns three arrays: allItems, someItems, otherItems.
In the appComponent I got switch statement:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="sectionSelected">
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'someItems'">
  <app-items></app-items>
  </p>
</div>
```

In the itemsComponent I got the following loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsArray" class="m-1 p-1">
some code {{ items.property }}
</div>
```

I want the itemsArray in ngFor to be set to the value of the case in the switch statment. The idea is to **loop through that selected array** instead of **generating sub-components** for each array which will have the same html code.
Is that possible? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **sectionSelected** has one of the given arrays (allItems, someItems, otherItems) at a given time. you don't need a switch statement.

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <p>
    <app-items [itemsArray]="sectionSelected"></app-items>
  </p>
</div>
```

In ItemsComponent

```
import { Input } from "@angular/core";
...
@Input() itemsArray: any[]; // you can give the specific type to the array instead
```

items.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsArray" class="m-1 p-1">
 some code {{ items.property }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.